# Why doesn't this PayPal button center align?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code to center align a PayPal donate button on a website but it still does not center align. Please guide why. Thanks.

```
<form     width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations"><input type="hidden" name="business" value="nayajeevan@njfk.org"><input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"><input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Naya Jeevan Foundation"><input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="26-0551721"><input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest"><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xfosrkpx/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xfosrkpx/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute style to your **input type='image'**:

```
style="display:block; margin:0 auto"
```

Updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/xfosrkpx/3/**

Answer (score 0):

You can add `text-align:center;` on your `<form>`.

The `<input>` is an inline element, you can center like a text with `text-align:center;`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in my question. The style item needs to be inside a style tag.

```
<form    style=" width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations"><input type="hidden" name="business" value="nayajeevan@njfk.org"><input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"><input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Naya Jeevan Foundation"><input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="26-0551721"><input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest"><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add css

```
CSS:
form{
   text-align: center;
}
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/mmp848ww/